# Flutter app grid view with search filter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-test

In this flutter code, I have implemented a Gridview with a search filter in AppBar. 
Currently showing only building name but I want to show building place name also?
is there any way I can filter both building names and place names?

1. I want to show building place name-value also in the gridview
2. When clicked a grid item how to get the item id?

   ```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:realpro/SizeConfig.dart';
   import 'package:realpro/root/dashscreen.dart';

   class SearchList extends StatefulWidget {
     SearchList({ Key key }) : super(key: key);
     @override
     _SearchListState createState() => new _SearchListState();
      }
     class _SearchListState extends State<SearchList>
     {
     Widget appBarTitle = new Text("My Properties", style: new TextStyle(color: 
     Colors.white),);
     Icon actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.orange,);
     final key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
     final TextEditingController _searchQuery = new TextEditingController();
     List<String>  _list;
     bool _IsSearching;
     String _searchText = "";
     _SearchListState() {
     _searchQuery.addListener(() {
     if (_searchQuery.text.isEmpty) {
     setState(() {
      _IsSearching = false;
      _searchText = "";
      });
      }
    else {
   setState(() {
     _IsSearching = true;
     _searchText = _searchQuery.text;
      });
     }
    });
    }
   @override
   void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _IsSearching = false;
   init();
   }
   void init() {
   _list = List();
   _list.add("building 1",);
   _list.add("building 2");
   _list.add("building 3");
   _list.add("building 4");
   _list.add("building 5");
   _list.add("building 6");
   _list.add("building 7");
   _list.add("building 8");
   _list.add("building 9");
   _list.add("building 10");
   }  
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   SizeConfig().init(context);
   return new Scaffold(
    key: key,
    appBar: buildBar(context),
    body: new GridView.count(
     crossAxisCount: 3,
     padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,10,10,10),
     childAspectRatio: 8.0 / 9.0,
     children: _IsSearching ? _buildSearchList() : _buildList(),
      ),
      drawer: Navigationdrawer(),
      );
       }
       List<Uiitem> _buildList() {
       return _list.map((contact) => new Uiitem(contact)).toList();
       }
       List<Uiitem> _buildSearchList() {
       if (_searchText.isEmpty) {
       return _list.map((contact) => new Uiitem(contact))
       .toList();
        }
       else {
       List<String> _searchList = List();
        for (int i = 0; i < _list.length; i++) {
        String  name = _list.elementAt(i);
        if (name.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase())) {
         _searchList.add(name);
         }
        }
       return _searchList.map((contact) => new Uiitem(contact))
       .toList();
       }
     }
     Widget buildBar(BuildContext context) {
      return new AppBar(
       centerTitle: true,
       title: appBarTitle,
       iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color:Colors.orange),
       backgroundColor: Colors.black,
       actions: <Widget>[
     new IconButton(icon: actionIcon, onPressed: () {
       setState(() {
         if (this.actionIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
           this.actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.orange,);
           this.appBarTitle = new TextField(
             controller: _searchQuery,
             style: new TextStyle(
               color: Colors.orange,
             ),
             decoration: new InputDecoration(
                 hintText: "Search here..",
                 hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
             ),
           );
           _handleSearchStart();
         }
         else {
           _handleSearchEnd();
            }
           });
         },),
        ]
      );
     }
      void _handleSearchStart() {
      setState(() {
      _IsSearching = true;
       });
      }
      void _handleSearchEnd() {
      setState(() {
      this.actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.orange,);
      this.appBarTitle =
      new Text("My Properties", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),);
      _IsSearching = false;
      _searchQuery.clear();
       });
      }
     }
    class Uiitem extends StatelessWidget{
    final String name;
    Uiitem(this.name);
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Card(
     margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5,5,5,7),
     elevation: 10.0,
     child: InkWell(
     splashColor: Colors.orange,
     onTap: (){
     },
    child: Column(
     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
     children: <Widget>[
     AspectRatio(
       aspectRatio: 18.0 / 11.0,
       child: Image.asset('assets/images/build.jpeg',fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,),
     ),
     Padding(
       padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 15.0, 0.0,0.0),
       child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
         children: <Widget>[
           Text(this.name,style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Raleway',fontWeight: 
      FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 14.0),
               maxLines: 1,
               ),
           SizedBox(height: 0.0),
           Text('Place',style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto'),),
         ],
          ),
         ),
       ],
      ),
      ),   
     );
     }
    }
   ```

   [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can define a `Building` class have attribute `id, name, place` 
Step 2: Return search list not return `List<Uiitem>` 
Step 3: Use `GridView.builder` and return  `Uiitem(_searchList[index]);` 
Step 4: `Uiitem` accept `Building` so your `InkWell` can get `id`

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Building {
  String id;
  String name;
  String place;

  Building({this.id, this.name, this.place});
}

class SearchList extends StatefulWidget {
  SearchList({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SearchListState createState() => _SearchListState();
}

class _SearchListState extends State<SearchList> {
  Widget appBarTitle = Text(
    "My Properties",
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  );
  Icon actionIcon = Icon(
    Icons.search,
    color: Colors.orange,
  );
  final key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final TextEditingController _searchQuery = TextEditingController();
  List<Building> _list;
  List<Building> _searchList = List();

  bool _IsSearching;
  String _searchText = "";
  _SearchListState() {
    _searchQuery.addListener(() {
      if (_searchQuery.text.isEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          _IsSearching = false;
          _searchText = "";
          _buildSearchList();
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _IsSearching = true;
          _searchText = _searchQuery.text;
          _buildSearchList();
        });
      }
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _IsSearching = false;
    init();
  }

  void init() {
    _list = List();
    _list.add(
      Building(id:"1", name: "A 1", place: "google"),
    );
    _list.add(
      Building(id:"2", name: "A 2", place: "google"),
    );
    _list.add(
      Building(id:"3",name: "B 3", place: "facebook"),
    );
    _list.add(
      Building(id:"4",name: "B 4", place: "facebook"),
    );
    _list.add(
      Building(id:"5",name: "C 5", place: "flutter"),
    );
    _searchList = _list;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
        key: key,
        appBar: buildBar(context),
        body: GridView.builder(
            itemCount: _searchList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Uiitem(_searchList[index]);
            },
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
            )

            /* GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
        childAspectRatio: 8.0 / 9.0,
        children: _IsSearching ? _buildSearchList() : _buildList(),
      ),*/
            //drawer: Navigationdrawer(),
            ));
  }

  List<Building> _buildList() {
    return _list; //_list.map((contact) =>  Uiitem(contact)).toList();
  }

  List<Building> _buildSearchList() {
    if (_searchText.isEmpty) {
      return _searchList =
          _list; //_list.map((contact) =>  Uiitem(contact)).toList();
    } else {
      /*for (int i = 0; i < _list.length; i++) {
        String name = _list.elementAt(i);
        if (name.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase())) {
          _searchList.add(name);
        }
      }*/

      _searchList = _list
          .where((element) =>
              element.name.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
              element.place.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      print('${_searchList.length}');
      return _searchList; //_searchList.map((contact) =>  Uiitem(contact)).toList();
    }
  }

  Widget buildBar(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: appBarTitle,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.orange),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: actionIcon,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (this.actionIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                  this.actionIcon = Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    color: Colors.orange,
                  );
                  this.appBarTitle = TextField(
                    controller: _searchQuery,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Search here..",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  );
                  _handleSearchStart();
                } else {
                  _handleSearchEnd();
                }
              });
            },
          ),
        ]);
  }

  void _handleSearchStart() {
    setState(() {
      _IsSearching = true;
    });
  }

  void _handleSearchEnd() {
    setState(() {
      this.actionIcon = Icon(
        Icons.search,
        color: Colors.orange,
      );
      this.appBarTitle = Text(
        "My Properties",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      );
      _IsSearching = false;
      _searchQuery.clear();
    });
  }
}

class Uiitem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Building building;
  Uiitem(this.building);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 7),
      elevation: 10.0,
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.orange,
        onTap: () {
          print(building.id);
        },
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 18.0 / 11.0,
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/build.jpeg',
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    this.building.name,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 14.0),
                    maxLines: 1,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 0.0),
                  Text(
                    building.place,
                    style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SearchList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but I want to keep the navigation drawer in there.

Comment: I do not have your drawer code. so I just remark it. you can add it back.